# Prove that there are infinitely many primes $q$ such that $q \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, when $n$ is prime.

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that there are infinitely many primes $q$ such that $q \equiv 1
>  \pmod{n}$, when $n$ is prime.
>
> Use the hint: Consider the order of $a + kN$ in the multiplicative
>    group of $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$, where $N=a^n-1$ and $k \in
>  \mathbb{Z}$

[This is copied from this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816528/infinitely-many-primes-congruent-to-1-mod-prime/817411#817411), the answer I found doesn't quite make sense to me, more specifically why is it that the $q_i \not\equiv 1 \pmod n$ ? Would anyone be able to explain it, here is the answer provided

> Let $q$ be a prime divisor of  $$ A = \frac{a^n-1}{a-1} =
>  a^{n-1}+a^{n-2} + \dots + a + 1, $$  then  $$ a^n-1 = A (a-1) \equiv 0
>  \pmod{q},$$ so by Fermat's little theorem either $q \vert a-1$ or $n
>  \vert q-1$ (or both). Now if $q$ is also a divisor of $a-1$, then  $$
>  0 \equiv A \equiv 1^{n-1} + 1^{n-2} + \dots + 1 \equiv n \pmod{q} $$
>    and so $q$ is also a divisor of $n$, so if we chose $a$ equal to a
>    multiple of $n$ then we are sure that a prime divisor $q$ of $A$ is
>    not a divisor of $a-1$.
>
> Now we can use Euclid's argument in the following way: suppose that
>    there is only a finite number of primes $\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, say
>    $q_1,q_2,\dots,q_k$, set $a = nq_1q_2\dots q_k$ or $a = n$ if $k=0$.
>    Let $q$ a divisor of $a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\dots+1$,  then by the previous
>    discussion $q$ is not a divisor of $a-1$, but $a^n \equiv 1\pmod{q}$
>    so  by Fermat's little theorme $n \vert q-1$, and we found a prime $q
>  \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, which by construction is not possibly any of the
>    $q_i$'s a contradiction.

Comment: Look at what $q$ divides. Can any $q_i$ divide the same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

The fact you need is that $q$ divides $a^n-1$, and $q_i$ cannot, since it divides $a^n$.

This is a special case of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression. The full theorem is harder to prove.

Comment: Where does it state that q divides $a^n$?

Comment: Also is it necessary to state $a=n$ if $k=0$?

Comment: That just depends on whether you've established a convention that the empty product is equal to 1.

Comment: It doesn't say that $q$ divides $a^n$.  But you set $a=nq_1\cdot\cdot\cdot q_k$, so $q_i$ divided $a$ and thus also $a^n$, for $1\le i\le k$.